# Checking if an element has another element within CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a WooCommerce element as a fluid "nav-bar" style that has no padding and button to the right, like the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

```html
<div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">

    <a href="~~~" tabindex="1" class="button wc-forward">Continue shopping</a> 
    “Product” has been added to your cart.  

</div>
```

Here's the style:

```css
.woocommerce-message {
  background: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px #ddd !important;
  border: 2px solid #8fae1b;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  padding: 0;
}

.woocommerce-message .button.wc-forward {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-left: 2px solid #8fae1b;
  background: #8fae1b;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2s opacity;
}
```

But sometimes the `.woocommerce-message` does not have a `button` element, so I'm left with zero padding and a squished look. I found the CSS selector `:has()`, and considered using it as `.woocommerce-message:has(button)` and applying style from there, but there's no browser support currently.

Is there another way to conditionally style this message based on whether or not a Button exists in the HTML?

Comment: just add top and bottom padding to the `.woocommerce-message`

Comment: Well, then I lose the fluid look with the button. There would be space around the button.

Comment: `.woocommerce-message:empty` ? perhaps - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

Comment: Hey @Paulie_D, good suggestion, but text is considered not empty in that selector. The `.woocommerce-message` will have text content, just not the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery (if possible) is a good way to solve this:

HTML (unaltered):

```html
<div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert">
    <a href="~~~" tabindex="1" class="button wc-forward">Continue shopping</a> 
    “Product” has been added to your cart.  
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.woocommerce-message {
    background: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #ddd !important;
    border: 2px solid #8fae1b;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.woocommerce-message .button.wc-forward {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-left: 2px solid #8fae1b;
    background: #8fae1b;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0.2s opacity;
}

/* Our new class */
.woocommerce-message-with-button {
    padding: 0;
    /* Add here all the CSS that should be applied to the message WITH button children */ 
}
```

JavaScript (using jQuery):

```js
if ($(".woocommerce-message").find("button").length) {
    $(".woocommerce-message").addClass("woocommerce-message-with-button");
} else {
    $(".woocommerce-message").removeClass("woocommerce-message-with-button");
}
```

Explanation:

In case our `woocommerce-message` element has children of type `button`, jQuery adds the class `woocommerce-message-with-button` and all the desired CSS is applied. In case there are no button children, it removes the class (if present). You can run this JavaScript when, for example, the user adds an item to the cart.

Click to read about [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/).

*Take note that using jQuery element class selector " . " will apply the style to ALL elements with that CSS class. Details [here](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).*

Comment: Fantastic. I'll write a Vanilla JS equivalent, thanks for this I didn't think of using JS.

Comment: I’m glad you liked it! If you need help, please let me know.